# Will my reputation increase if I merge my account with another one?

Tags: discussion, merge-accounts

I want to merge my Stack Overflow account with my other account with  decent reputation. I want to know if my reputation increase after merge?

How should I merge both accounts?

Comment: Yes, and may get decrease if you have done cross votting.

Comment: [Merging accounts](http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: Is this another account on Stack Overflow or an account on another site? If it's the latter then they can't be merged. If it's the former, then select the "I need to merge user profiles" option [here](http://stackoverflow.com/contact)

Comment: @ChrisF, what is latter & former account ?

Comment: @Kedarnath - latter == accounts on other SE sites (eg. Super User). Former == another account on SO.

Comment: i have only on SO no other accounts @ChrisF

Comment: If you have a different user on SO than on the rest of the network, just extend one of the accounts so you have both on some SE-site, and request the merge there.

Comment: It did, in my case. Even that one answer I posted with my previous profile shows up.

Answer (score 8):

To merge accounts select the

> "I need to merge user profiles"

option [here](https://stackoverflow.com/contact)

As long as there has been no cross voting between the accounts then the result should be that the remaining account has the sum of reputations of the two accounts. If the reputation earned by the two accounts **from *legitimate* votes** on any day was > 200 then the merged account will be rep capped for those days.

Comment: Is this true even if one account got 150 reputation on the same day that the other account got 100 reputation? Or will it be subject to the daily rep limit and lose 50? (ignoring bounties, etc.)

Comment: @arserbin3 - Yes the totals will be subject to the daily rep limit.

Answer (score 5):

> I want to know if my reputation increase after merge?

Depends. If either of them have voted for each other, no. Because any votes either account has cast towards the other will be deleted from the system upon merging, and any reputation gained from those votes will disappear.

If there's absolutely nothing going on between the two of them, then your new reputation will end up being both reputation values added together, minus the 1 reputation you start with (if you merge two accounts with 1 reputation, your new reputation is 1, not 2).

Comment: Does the merge also cater for multiple association bonuses?

Comment: @JonClements Good catch. Yes it does. Potentially another 100 that could be lost in some situations.

Comment: Does it account for the daily rep limit?

Comment: @SomePerson Yes. Behind the scenes it just moves all the posts to the new account. It then runs a full recalc on their account. It doesn't *actually* just add the reputations together. Just a simple way of thinking about it. Generally with account merges we only ever see rep losses from invalidated votes, so that was the only thing that came to mind from experience.