# Is transferring Stack Overflow reputation from one account to another using bounties allowed?

Tags: discussion, bounty, ethics, sock-puppets

I currently have another older Stack Overflow account with the username of [LIL LOFIE](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13349935/lil-lofie).

I used that account when I was a beginner, and due to the huge amount of downvotes and demotivation due to my own mistakes, I left that account and created this one about a year ago.

I still have that account with some reputation. If I place a bounty on one of the questions I have on this account from my old account and give my own answer (which is currently the only answer) the bounty reward, would it be considered okay or would it be considered sock-puppeting?

I think that this question may come up in others' minds because I am pretty sure there are a lot of people who created new Stack Exchange accounts when they were beginners to avoid embarrassment and may have thought of doing (or even did) this, so your answer may help them as well.

Comment: What's about the accounts merging option for your case? [Will my reputation increase if I merge my account with another one?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253828/will-my-reputation-increase-if-i-merge-my-account-with-another-one)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the rules governing multiple accounts (i.e. sockpuppets)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388984/what-are-the-rules-governing-multiple-accounts-i-e-sockpuppets)

Comment: You're asking because you don't plan to have both accounts active at once?  It's obviously against the rules stated in [What are the rules governing multiple accounts (i.e. sockpuppets)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388984), so this seems at first glance like a duplicate.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

It's not allowed!

Please don't attempt this as this would result in your new account being deleted and the old one getting suspended.

If you want to keep the posts and gained reputation from them on your new account, you can ask to [have them merged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts). Moderators cannot do it, so you need to fill out the [contact us](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) form and ask staff to do it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249597/discussion-on-answer-by-dharman-is-transferring-stack-overflow-reputation-from-o).