# Does merging accounts also link edits and flags?

Tags: support, accounts, merge-accounts

I'm thinking about merging this old account with a newer one, but I'm worried about this. My newer account has >80 flags and about 40 edits (accepted, not flagged against the account), but apparently you can only merge into the older account.

If I merge my accounts, will badges, flags, edits, everything transfer or is it only rep, questions and answers? (I don't want to lose the Deputy badge.) I don't have a problem with changing my display name, but this is really bugging me.

Comment: A staff member (animuson) describes how a merge is done in a comment of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/337326 But there is no specific statement on other actions  than posts.

Comment: In that case, is it possible just to have the stuff transferred to my new account? (This is my active account in case you are wondering)

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, yes. Anything tied to your account gets moved to the target account when merging. This includes everything from posts to votes, flags, and login credentials.

There's some checks for consistency after the merge, but they're mainly aimed at votes (incredibly oversimplified, [up/down, 1234, 1234] (type, source, target) is invalid because you can't upvote yourself, so it gets cleared). But if it's tied to the source account, your new account does get it.

Note that immediately after the merge itself, there may be a delay due to various caches needing to catch up. I don't remember how badges tie into the merge system, but I believe they may be temporarily removed (possibly with some exceptions for certain unique badges), and then recalculated. Assuming this is the case, this means there's a chance there's an hour or two where you don't have the deputy badge.

Your flags will still be present on the target account, however, so you'll get it the next time the system decides to update badges. It won't be lost after the merge, but it may be delayed.

> but apparently you can only merge into the older account.

Not sure where you have this from, but that's not the case. Merges aren't dependent on account age. You can merge the newer into the older, or the older into the newer without any problems. We've seen both happen with vote fraud escalations leading to account merges, for instance.

If anything, aside vote fraud cases, it's probably more common to merge the older into the newer, because people make an account, do stuff, forget about it, come back to the site, make a new account, do stuff, and then realise they have an old account they'd like to recover.

In the grand scheme of things though, it doesn't really matter. You still end up with an account containing the same things, and you can log into it the same way as you used to.

Comment: Thanks, this helped! Do you know how I can merge the older account into the newer account, though? When I try and merge from the Contact form, it only shows merging to the older account.

Comment: @RedzMakesErrors where do you see that? The contact form only mentions "your profile link" and "your other profile link": https://i.stack.imgur.com/F94Je.png - you can probably also mention that you'd like one account to be merged into another specifically in the message, for good measure

Comment: After I verify that I own both the accounts, the system takes me to a page which says (Confirm merge, everything will be moved to Skyrider Feyrs) which is my old account. I am trying to merge into this account.

Comment: Here's what I see after I confirm the emails: Thank you for confirming ownership of your accounts. The account RedzMakesErrors will be removed, and all rep and votes will be transferred to account Skyrider Feyrs as a result of this merge. Please click OK to confirm.

Comment: @RedzMakesErrors I didn't know it has a fancy UI now. Do you have an email from the support team you could reply to? You could write a reply and ask for the merge direction to be reversed and see if that helps

Comment: No, I don't have an email. Also, it says that if I put in a request it won't be looked at until the next business day... which is a couple months away since I'm in the holidays XD

Comment: @RedzMakesErrors SE employees are still at work AFAIK, so shouldn't be too long

Comment: Ok, should I put it on Other instead of account merge or do I just go with account merge and not merge yet?

Comment: I assume either is fine. There's a human involved when you contact them, so they'll be able to figure it out

Comment: Nope, the merge direction can't be reversed.